# Redirecting files without extension to specific URL and ignore files with extension

Tags: .htaccess

I have 3 URLs:

- domainname.com/add.php
- domainname.com/list.php
- domainname.com/showcase (**showcase** WORD can keep changing as it is used on affiliate website, this is not fixed)

When user enter **domainname.com/showcase** , this should redirect to **domainname.com/redirect.php?shortcode=$1** but when user choose **domainname.com/add.php** OR **domainname.com/list.php**, it should open that specific page and do not re-direct.

I have written below script in .htaccess, it redirect **domainname.com/showcase** correctly but it is also redirecting **domainname.com/add.php** and **domainname.com/list.php**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ redirect.php?shortcode=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Please advice how can I stop redirection for **domainname.com/add.php** and **domainname.com/list.php** and keep **domainname.com/showcase** redirecting as of now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `RewriteCond` to exclude your existing files from the redirection

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#exclude dirs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#exclude files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ redirect.php?shortcode=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```